# Concurrent Insertions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, migration, postgresql-12

The documentation for migrating to PostgreSQL 12.6 says

> Concurrent insertions could lead to a corrupt index with entries placed in the wrong pages. It's recommended to reindex any GiST index that's been subject to concurrent insertions.

I am hoping for some clarity on the definition of a "concurrent insertion." Does it simply refer to the case when two transactions are attempting to update the same table?

Comment: Yes, precisely.